# Magento2 : How can I add filters to frontend so it should work like a backend filter?

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, backend, filter

i'm working on adding custom filter for this custom module

> i want to add filters (Q_ID,Q_STATUS,Q_PRICE) it would work like back
>   end filter Magento admin

how i add filter and any idea's??
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is the reference link

http://magefoo.com/building-an-admin-grid-in-the-front-end-of-magento-2/

https://belvg.com/blog/ui-grid-component-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2.html

I hope so it's work for you.

Comment: can i add for every tab....